# Distribution Function Conditioned On Geometric Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

Let $X’_is$ be independent random variables with some common distribution function $F$, and suppose they are independent of$N$, a geometric random variable with parameter $p$. If $M = max(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$, obtain the distribution function of $M$ while conditioning on $N$.

My approach :

Since $M$ is independent of $N$, I just divided the distribution function of $M$ by $P(X=n)$

So I get,
$$F_{M|N}(m|n) = \frac{[F_X(a)]^n}{(1-p)^{n-1}p} $$

I am not sure if this is the right method and answer, can someone clarify and provide the correct method if this is wrong.

Comment: Do you mean $M = \max(X_1,\dots,X_N)$? Because otherwise $M$ is independent of $N$.

Comment: @TkiDeneb yes i mean this

Comment: "Since "$M$ is independent of $N$..."  $M$ can't be independent of $N$.  The larger the sample size, the larger the observed values of $M$ will be.  So $N$ affects the distribution of $M$..

Comment: I suspect you are looking for the marginal cumulative distribution function of $M$ rather than the distribution of $M$ conditioned on $N$.  To do that you'll need to sum over the values of $F(x|N=n)*Pr(N=n)$ for $n=1$ to $n=\infty$.  And there are some assumptions of $F$ being absolutely continuous.